# How to find the sides of a triangle if all angles of the triangle are known

Tags: geometry

In a triangle, if all angles are known, how is it possible to find all the 3 sides, using just this much information?

Comment: Knowing the three angles only defines the triangle up to scale.  If you declare one side to be $1$, say, you can use the Law of Sines to get the other two.

Comment: Every equilateral triangle has $60^\circ$ angles. But the side lengths can be any length whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. When you dilate a triangle, its angles stay the same. Thus, given all three angles, the sides can be anything as long as they stay in proportion.

However, we can find the exact proportions of the sides given the angles.
For this, the law of sines is useful.

$$\frac{A}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{B}{\sin \beta}=\frac{C}{\sin \gamma}$$

Where $A$ is the length of the side opposite angle $\alpha$, $B$ is the length of the side opposite angle $\beta$, and $C$ is the length of the side opposite angle $\gamma$.